# function() used as value compile error

Tags: go

I'm trying to learn the basics of Go by tweaking examples as I go along the tutorial located here:

http://tour.golang.org/#9

---

Here's a small function I wrote that just turns ever character to all caps.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func capitalize(name string) {
    name = strings.ToTitle(name)
    return
}

func main() {
    test := "Sergio"    
    fmt.Println(capitalize(test))
}
```

I'm getting this exception:

> prog.go:15: capitalize(test) used as value

Any glaring mistakes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are missing the return type for `capitalize()`:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "strings"
)

func capitalize(name string) string {
        return strings.ToTitle(name)
}

func main() {
        test := "Sergio"
        fmt.Println(capitalize(test))
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Fn8vKHUOBI)

---

Output:

```
SERGIO
```

Comment: Gah, I forgot the return type for the function didn't I?

Comment: yepp. And you did assign to the argument instead of to the return value.

Comment: @FUZxxl: There's nothing wrong with that. In Go, arguments are passed by value. For example, `func capitalize(name string) string { name = strings.ToTitle(name); return name }`.

Comment: @peterSO I know that. I wanted to point out that this did not do what OP wanted.