# Middleware pattern in Go - 'used as value' compile error

Tags: go, middleware

I am trying to make middleware to my functions similar to the pattern used for http.HandlerFunc, this usually works:

```
func middleware(fn http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func (wr http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println("doing something before")
        fn(wr, r)
    }
}

func main() {
    middleware(func (wr http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        wr.Write([]byte("..."))
    })
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type FN func (arg int)

func myFunc(arg int) {
    fmt.Println("Arg:",arg)
}
// Logically here I am returning the function not it's value
// http package does this identically, I don't see the difference
func do(fn FN) FN {
    return func (arg int) {
        fn(arg)
    }
}

func main() {
    do(myFunc(3))
}
```

Will return compile error: myFunc(3) used as value

As you can see here:
https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=64103:64150#L2055

On line 2065:

```
// The HandlerFunc type is an adapter to allow the use of
// ordinary functions as HTTP handlers. If f is a function
// with the appropriate signature, HandlerFunc(f) is a
// Handler that calls f.
type HandlerFunc func(ResponseWriter, *Request)
```

This function signature also does not return a value yet this compiles.

### UPDATE:

This pattern is what I was trying to achieve, which now works.

```
package main

import (
 "fmt"
)

type FN func (arg int)
func do(fn FN) FN {
    return func (arg int) {
    fmt.Println("executed do with arg",arg)
    // some other code ...
    fn(arg) // call wrapped function
   }
}
func something(arg int){
fmt.Println("Executed something with arg",arg)
}

func main() {
   do(something)(3)
}
```

Output:

```
executed do with arg 3
Executed something with arg 3

Program exited.
```

Comment: `myFunc` returns nothing. But you're calling it in a context where its return value is needed. This is what the error means.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12561162/13860, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596805/function-used-as-value-compile-error

Comment: @Flimzy But as far as I can see func (wr http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {} also doesn't return any value

Comment: But you're not calling that function in a context where a return value is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `myFunc(arg int)` - which doesn't return anything, and trying to pass it's return value into `do`.  It looks like maybe you want to do:

```
func main() {
    do(myFunc)(3)
}
```

but not really sure